# VBA/Excel Else without if - error for binomial calculation

Tags: vba

I am doing binomical calculations the long way in VBA/ Excel. I have constructed my own factorial function - which works called getFact(). Whenever I try to run my code I get an error Else without If. I have tried debugging it and the code will work for the first option on the menu "Selection 1: exact" but not for any other options on the menu: at least, at most, more than, greater than..etc

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Binomial_click()
Dim n As Integer
Dim p As Double 
Dim q As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim Selection As Integer
Dim results As Double
Dim fromo As Double
Dim too As Double
'start of proc

MsgBox ("this will calculate the binomial")

Selection = InputBox("1. Exact" & vbNewLine _
& "2. At Least" & vbNewLine _
& "3. At Most" & vbNewLine _
& "4. Greater than" & vbNewLine _
& "5. Less than" & vbNewLine _
& "6. Between")

'parameters needed

n = InputBox("input number of trials")
p = InputBox("input probabilty")
q = 1 - p


If Selection = 1 Then 'exact
r = InputBox("input success")
results = getFact(n) / (getFact(n - r) * getFact(r)) * p ^ r * q ^ (n - r)
MsgBox ("your result is" & results)

ElseIf Selection = 2 Then 'at least
r = InputBox("input success") 'asks for successes
For i = r To n
results = results + getFact(n) / getFact(n - i) * getFact(i) * p ^ i * q ^ 
(n - i)



ElseIf Selection = 3 Then 'at most
r = InputBox("input success") 'asks for successes
For i = 0 To r
results = results + getFact(n) / (getFact(n - i) * getFact(i)) * p ^ i * q ^ 
(n - i)

ElseIf Selection = 4 Then 'greater than
r = InputBox("input success") 'asks for successes
s = r + 1
For i = s To n
results = results + getFact(n) / (getFact(n - i) * getFact(i)) * p ^ i * q ^ 
(n - i)


ElseIf Selection = 5 Then 'less than
r = InputBox("input success") 'asks for successes
s = r - 1
For i = 0 To s
results = results + getFact(n) / (getFact(n - i) * getFact(i)) * p ^ i * q ^ 
(n - i)


ElseIf Selection = 6 Then 'between
fromo = InputBox("input from")
too = InputBox("input to")
For i = fromo To too
results = results + getFact(n) / (getFact(n - i) * getFact(i)) * p ^ i * q ^ 
(n - i)

MsgBox ("your results are" & results)



 End If

 End Sub
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You should download: [Rubberduck VBA](http://rubberduckvba.com/).  Using its Code Formatter will allow you to quitely catch problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `Next` statement to end each of your `For` loops, e.g.

```
For i = 0 To s
    results = results + getFact(n) / (getFact(n - i) * getFact(i)) * p ^ i * q ^ (n - i)
Next
```

---

Refactored code (to avoid multiple copies of the calculation loop) might be:

```
Sub test()
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim p As Double
    Dim q As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim s As Integer
    Dim Selection As Integer
    Dim results As Double
    Dim fromo As Double
    Dim too As Double
    'start of proc

    MsgBox "this will calculate the binomial"

    Selection = InputBox("1. Exact" & vbNewLine _
        & "2. At Least" & vbNewLine _
        & "3. At Most" & vbNewLine _
        & "4. Greater than" & vbNewLine _
        & "5. Less than" & vbNewLine _
        & "6. Between")

    'parameters needed

    n = InputBox("input number of trials")
    p = InputBox("input probabilty")
    q = 1 - p


    Select Case Selection
    If Selection = 1 Then 'exact
        r = InputBox("input success")
        fromo = r
        too = r

    ElseIf Selection = 2 Then 'at least
        r = InputBox("input success") 'asks for successes
        fromo = r
        too = n

    ElseIf Selection = 3 Then 'at most
        r = InputBox("input success") 'asks for successes
        fromo = 0
        too = r

    ElseIf Selection = 4 Then 'greater than
        r = InputBox("input success") 'asks for successes
        fromo = r + 1
        too = n

    ElseIf Selection = 5 Then 'less than
        r = InputBox("input success") 'asks for successes
        fromo = 0
        too = r - 1

    ElseIf Selection = 6 Then 'between
        fromo = InputBox("input from")
        too = InputBox("input to")

    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid selection"
        Exit Sub

    End If

    For i = fromo To too
        results = results + getFact(n) / (getFact(n - i) * getFact(i)) * p ^ i * q ^ (n - i)
    Next
    MsgBox "your results are" & results

End Sub
```

Comment: @ThomasInzina I actually started to put a `Select Case` in and then reverted back to the `If` / `ElseIf` that the OP had been using.  (I decided to go for a one step at a time approach to training. :D)

Comment: Nice case on the initial use case.  It is not obvious that the formulas are the same and that it only needed to be ran once.

Comment: @YowE3k Thank you so so much for your help! I didn't realise that about the next statements. The loop makes it much clearer!  Thank you

Comment: @YowE3K hi there, I am getting a 'run time error' division by zero, do you know why this is please?

Comment: I assume you are getting that on the `results = results + getFact(n) / (getFact(n - i) * getFact(i)) * p ^ i * q ^ (n - i)` statement.  It means that either `getFact(n - i)` is zero or `getFact(i)` is zero.